# Disable click on alpha channel of embedded PNG?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm using PNGs with alpha channels in a D3 project. The images are clickable. Is there an SVG property to signal d3 to ignore the mouse when it is over a transparent area of the image?

If I can do that with PNGs, could I possible do it with an embedded SVG?

Animation shows the cursor change as when it is within the rect of the image. I would like to limit the active area to the opaque parts of the image.

---

Adding some more detail after researching this a bit more:

From the [ww3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html)

> For raster images, hit-testing is either performed on a whole-image
>   basis (i.e., the rectangular area for the image is one of the
>   determinants for whether the image receives the event) **or on a
>   per-pixel basis (i.e., the alpha values for pixels under the pointer
>   help determine whether the image receives the event):**
>
> The value visiblePainted means that the raster image can receive events anywhere within the bounds of the image **if any pixel from the
>   raster image which is under the pointer is not fully transparent**, with
>   the additional requirement that the ‘visibility’ property is set to
>   visible.

I've tried adding the CSS below to the image element but the entire rect of the image still remains clickable.

```
.clickable {
     cursor: pointer;
     pointer-events: visiblePainted;
     visibility: visible;
 }
```

---

[image]

---

```
 e.append("image")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return margin_content.left - (d.iconWidth / 2);
                })
                .attr("y", - d.iconHeight)
                .attr("width", d.iconWidth)
                .attr("height", d.iconHeight)
                .attr("xlink:href", iconImagePath)
                .attr("class", "clickable")
                .on("click", eventClick);
```

Comment: Are you sure the click event is really raised, and it is not only the cursor changing? Per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty), the default `pointer-events:visiblePainted` should not raise events on fully transparent pixels.

Comment: @ccprog – thanks for the reply. Yes, I put a log statement in the even handler and it outputs when I click on the alpha area within the rect of the image. I am wondering if there is some additional property I can set.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure those pixels are fully transparent? If there's a drop shadow anywhere, it can cause low but still positive alpha values a surprising distance from the object.

Comment: @MichaelMullany – thanks for the reply. Yes, I just checked again and even exported a new PNG to ensure a transparent background. Same issue – and my searches so far have not turned up any discussion of this (hard to narrow in on effective search terms).